# How to convert a character timestamp column into a date-time object in R

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I have a dataset with a chr column with the format:

> "2000-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC"

How do you convert it into a date-time object in R? I tried using the following but it is giving me NAs.

> as.POSIXct(data$date, format="%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z")

Comment: It's a FAQ. You need `%Y` for four digits years. Or use `anytime::anytime()` which requires no format string.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ymd_hms`

```
library(lubridate)
ymd_hms(str1)
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "2000-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC"
```